# What program can I use to turn a panoramic image (jpg) into a panning video (1080p mp4 or mov)

Tags: video

I'm looking for some kind of app (preferably free) that will help me take a panoramic image and make a video that is panning across. I want the image to fill the entire screen (no black bars) and the output should be HD (1080 is preferable, 720 is ok). I'm running a Windows PC. Anybody know of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Powerpoint 2010 and making the image have a panning exit animation. I exported deck as a video.
This kind of worked, but it didn't really give a great output. It was pretty choppy.